# python zipfile basename

Tags: python

I have some homework that I am trying to complete. I don't want the answer. I'm just having trouble in starting. The work I have tried is not working at all... Can someone please just provide a push in the right direction. I am trying to learn but after trying and trying I need some help.

I know I can you `os.path.basename()` to get the basename and then add it to the file name but I can't get it together.

Here is the assignment

In this project, write a function that takes a directory path and creates an archive of the directory only. For example, if the same path were used as in the example `("c:\\xxxx\\Archives\\archive_me")`, the zipfile would contain `archive_me\\groucho`, `archive_me\\harpo` and `archive_me\\chico`.

The base directory (`archive_me` in the example above) is the final element of the input, and all paths recorded in the zipfile should start with the base directory.

If the directory contains sub-directories, the sub-directory names and any files in the sub-directories should not be included. (Hint: You can use `isfile()` to determine if a filename represents a regular file and not a directory.)

Thanks again any direction would be great.

Answer (score 5):

It would help to know what you tried yourself, so I'm only giving a few pointers to methods in the standard libraries:

- [`os.listdir`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir) to get the a list of files and folders under a given directory (beware, it returns only the file/folder name, not the full path!)
- [`os.path.isfile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile) as mentioned in the assignment to check if a given path represents a file or a folder
- [`os.path.isdir`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.isdir), the opposite of `os.path.isfile` (thanks [inspectorG4adget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13505569/python-zipfile-basename#comment18485374_13505610))
- [`os.path.join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to join a filename with the basedir without having to worry about slashes and delimiters
- [`ZipFile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile) for handling, well, zip files
- [`zipFile.write`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile#zipfile.ZipFile.write) to write the files found to the zip

I'm not sure you'll need all of those, but it doesn't hurt knowing they exist.

Comment: Also, `os.path.isdir` determines if the given path points to a directory